# My table rows shows the same data on each row - data feched from xml files

Tags: arrays

I'm new at Javascript and i'm trying to pull data from multiple XML files.

Right now i have maneged to create 5 rows of data, but all rows contains data from the same file.

I have been trying to store the data in another array than the original one, but nothing i have tried seems too work.

My HTML code is here:

```
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()" >Get my PTO DATA</button>
    <br><br>
        <table id="demo">
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>

</body>
```

And Javascript here:

```
var arr = ["018338464.xml", "018340087.xml", "018340096.xml", "018340106.xml", "018340153.xml"],
    cnt = 0, xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(), method = "GET";




function loadXMLDoc() {
   
    xmlhttp.open(method, arr[cnt], true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            buildTable();
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}





function buildTable(file, xmlDoc) {
    var i;
    var a = 1
    var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    var table = "<tr><th>DisplayNumber</th><th>Client</th><th>IpgClientId</th><th>Location</th><th>PracticeArea</th><th>Type</th><th>Application number</th><th>Application date</th><th>Classes</th><th>Class description</th><th>Status</th></tr>";
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Transaction");
    for (var d = 0; d < arr.length; d++) {
        console.log(`${d}: ${arr[d]}`);
        var store = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            table += "<tr><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("TransactionIdentifier")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("MarkVerbalElementText")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("Identifier")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("RegistrationOfficeCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("TransactionCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("MarkFeature")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("ApplicationNumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("ApplicationDate")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("ClassNumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("GoodsServicesDescription")[2].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td><td>" +
                x[i].getElementsByTagName("MarkCurrentStatusCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
                "</td></tr>";

            
        }
        store[d] = a;
        a++;
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
```

All feedback are welcome, i'm also open to redo it all if someone has a better solution to my problem

Answer (score 0):

You always load `arr[cnt]`, and `cnt` is always zero.  If you want `loadXMLDoc` to load the entire set, then you want

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  arr.forEach( function(name) {
    xmlhttp.open(method, name, true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            buildTable();
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
  });
}
```

Comment: The solution you provided wasn't the end goal for my problem - I have been trying something similar, but not i the way you have written her. 

The result of the code you have given me now gives the same value in all 5 rows of the last element in the array - any suggestions hw i fix that ?

Comment: I don't know.  The best you can do is echo some lines to the console in loadXMLDoc and make sure you're getting what you think you should get.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem - Your suggestion lead me to the right answer - Thanks